# Invalid url for content item created in a tree of sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to create a simple parent child pages in a sitecore tree as follows,

```
Home
 Test
   Test1
     Test3
   Test2
      Test4
```

When I publish and check the url as http://test.com/Test/Test1 or http://test.com/Test/Test1/Test3

I am not able to access it and gives the following error

```
The requested document was not found

Most likely causes: •The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
What you can try:
 Go back to the previous page  
 Go to the start page  
 More information  
Requested URL: /test/ 
User Name: extranet\Anonymous 
Site Name: website 
If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in the web.config.
```

Please let me know if I am messing anything or a setting.

Comment: Check if the templates that are used by Test, Test1, etc items are published. And if the items are not in a workflow that would prevent them from being published.

Comment: I have applied the right templated .So Ideally when i create any tree structure with an appropriate template should work right

Comment: With layout's assigned it should work yes. Are you able to preview the pages?

Comment: @Selwyn Are you sure your pages are not under a workflow ? If you were using the Sample Item - it might be the case.

Comment: How does it turn out in PageEditor? Are you able to navigate and view?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend u to open the Sitecore Desktop and switch to the "Web database" on the bottom right of your screen. If you are in the web database go and take a look if the items that you have created are all published in the web database.

Also you want to check quickly if this is a publish problems you can also put your website into live mode by putting the master connection string over the web one, cause that way you will just see all master content on your website.

Comment: You do not need to put the master connection string over the web one. You can go to your <site/> configuration element and set the database attribute value to "master".

Comment: True, forgot about that ;)!